# Highly Available requirement in Distributed Environment

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, cloud, distributed-computing, high-availability

I need to design a distributed HA (High Availability) solution in cloud. The backend resources should be distributed across multiple availability domains and fault domains (FD are sub-part of AD)in a way that we avoid skewness of resources.

Is there a design/architecture pattern that can be followed to achieve this. For example:
Suppose we have 3 AD and each AD has 3 FD , and say we have 10 resources to distribute with the condition that if can't allocate in 1 FD move to other FD (fail-safe condition).

I tried allocating ADs directly to resources in a loop to uniformly distribute it.
Ex :
8 Resource

```
AD1 (3)-> FD1 1 , FD2 1,  FD3 1
AD2 (3)-> FD1 1 , FD2 1 , FD3 1
AD3 (2)-> FD1 1 , FD2 1 , FD3 1
```

But want some better solution to allocate with fail-safe method.

Comment: In this particular question what does `AD` stand for?

Comment: what is better solution mean for you? I mean what are you trying to optimize for? If uniform distribution is your only concern then I think your solution is good. Only thing I will change is first distribute among ADs ( like 1 to each AD ) and then add second resource to AD in different FD.